# Match pandas column values of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

**Set-up**

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

1. `df_ads`: each row contains info on one scraped housing ad and `df_ads['ad_post_code']` contains the ad's Dutch postal code.
2. `df_mapping`: a mapping between postal codes and [NUTS3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_statistical_regions_of_the_Netherlands) regions

I need to map each ad's postal code into its NUTS3 region.

---

**Dataframes**

`df_ads['ad_post_code']` looks like,

```
0                1567 JA
1                3893 GB
2                5091 BE
3                1087 MB
4                7905 GW
5                5121 ZH
```

where `len(df_ads['ad_post_code']) = 85447`.

`df_mapping` looks like,

```
      CODE NUTS_3
0     1011  NL326
1     1012  NL326
2     1013  NL326
3     1014  NL326
4     1015  NL326
5     1016  NL326
```

where `len(df_mapping) = 4074`, `df_mapping['CODE']` display the first 4 characters of a Dutch postal code and `df_mapping['NUTS_3']` is the postal code's NUTS3 region.

In other words, postal code `1011` falls in NUTS3 region `NL326`.

---

**Problem**

I've done some straightforward looping to map the ads in `df_ads` into NUTS3 regions. However, I seem incapable of writing a correct looping set-up.

```
nuts3_map = []

# insert postal codes into list
for i in range(0,len(df_ads)):

    postal_code_ad = df_ads['ad_post_code'].iloc[i].split()[0]

    for j in range(0,len(df_mapping)):

        postal_code_map = str(df_mapping['CODE'].iloc[j])

        # check if postal code match
        if postal_code_ad == postal_code_map:

            nuts3_map.append(df_mapping['NUTS_3'].iloc[j])

            break
    continue
```

Running this gives `len(nuts3_map) = 85353` while `len(df_ads) = 85448`, such that `df_ads['nuts3'] = nuts3` gives `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`.

Is a double for loop the fastest way to do this? If so, how do I fix my for loop such that it all works well?

Comment: You should be able to complete this with a map or a merge over both data frames. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with two inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create another column in `df_ads`:

```
# If `df_mapping['CODE']` is `int`
df_ads['CODE'] = df_ads['ad_post_code'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:4]))

# If `df_mapping['CODE']` is `str`
# df_ads['CODE'] = df_ads['ad_post_code'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
```

Then I would use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to perform an inner merge of the two dataframes:

```
df_ads.merge(df_mapping, left_on='CODE', right_on='CODE', how='inner')
```

I took the liberty of modifying your data to produce a workable example:

```
# df_ads['ad_post_code']
0    1567 JA
1    3893 GB
2    5091 BE
3    1087 MB
4    7905 GW
5    5121 ZH
6    1011 XX

# df_mapping
   CODE NUTS_3
0  1011  NL326
1  1012  NL326
2  1013  NL326
3  1014  NL326
4  1015  NL326
5  1016  NL326
6  1567  XSFDF
```

Output:

```
  ad_post_code  CODE NUTS_3
0      1567 JA  1567  XSFDF
1      1011 XX  1011  NL326
```

If every code in `df_ads['CODE']` exists in `df_mapping['CODE']` then you shoud get the correct output.

**EDIT**

If you want to know if the list in `df_mapping` is complete, you can do this:

df_ads.loc[np.logical_not(df_ads['CODE'].isin(df_mapping['CODE']))]

Missing data:

```
   ad_post_code  CODE
id                   
1       3893 GB  3893
2       5091 BE  5091
3       1087 MB  1087
4       7905 GW  7905
5       5121 ZH  5121
```